# When user kills the app what method should I call?

Tags: iphone

I am have a trouble with the delegate method when the user kills the app using the red minus close button in the task switcher.

I've ever tried using `exit(0)` on `applicationWillTerminate` but that did not work.

Comment: On stack overflow, if one of the answers below solves your problem you need to accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer you want. Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything when the user closes the app or `[applicationWillTerminate:]` except clean up any things you may need to clean up.

You do not call `exit()`, and if you do so its likely the app will be rejected. Same with `abort()`.

If you need to close your app when the user dismisses it, the only think you can do is set the plist flag that sets the app to exit instead of going to background.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a callback when the user quits your app using the red minus button in the iOS recent apps list. Your app gets killed with a `SIGKILL` and there is no way to know.

You should save all your data and do everything you need to do to be prepared to be quit in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

in the app delegate. This could possibly be the last call your application gets so be ready.